# how to post json to shopify rest service using restclient

Tags: .net, json

Can anybody help with posting to shopify or it might be the format of json im not syre ive tried httpclient and restclient with no luck my json data looks like 
    {"order": {"line_items": [{"variant_id": 720123393,"quantity": 1}]}}
using curl I and having the data as a txt file it works but i just cant seem to get it to work in .net i get back {"errors":{"order":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

```
 var client = new RestClient(baseAddress);
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);
            // {"order": {"line_items": [{"variant_id": 720123393,"quantity": 1}]}}

            string data = @"{""order"": {""line_items"": [{""variant_id"": 720123393,""quantity"": 1}]}}";


            var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("admin/orders.json", RestSharp.Method.POST) { RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json }
            .AddBody(data);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I would add the resolution to this but im banned see http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/converting-an-object-into-json-object-148140 as a pointer